# Vimeo API: how to save a vimeo into a subfolder?

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

Which api allow me as developer to move a video into a folder?

I, for example, have the video `https://vimeo.com/12345678`.

In my personal area, I created the folder "DEV" under "Video". Opening in the browser, it is linked as `https://vimeo.com/manage/folders/20417534`

I tried the following call

```
POST https://api.vimeo.com/me/albums/20417534/videos/12345678
```

But I got an error complaining about album doesn't exist.

I supposed this is not the right API to call.

**Which API must I call to specify in which folder to save the video?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the `/me/albums/` path, which is incorrect. You need to use the `/projects/` path instead (Vimeo originally named the feature "projects" but later changed it to "folders". The API still uses the original naming convention).

To add the video at `/videos/12345678` to the folder at `https://vimeo.com/manage/folders/20417534`, make this request:

```
PUT https://api.vimeo.com/me/projects/20417534/videos/12345678
```

Alternatively, you could replace the `/me/` path with `/users/666666666/` if you want to use your userid, but `/me/` is a nice shortcut, since this request can only really succeed with your own folder anyway.

That endpoint is documented here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/projects#add_video_to_project

Comment: Can we upload videos to any of subfolers?? Like if I upload to "https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos"..it is uploaded to general folder. How can I iupload to specific folder..

Comment: @cyrus000 You have to upload the video first before you can add it to a folder; it's not possible to upload directly into a folder. Only the individual video's specific metadata (name, description, privacy settings, etc.) can be set on upload. All other actions require additional calls to the API. See here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#setting-video-metadata

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to upload then move the video. You can specify the parameter `folder_uri` and just send in the uri of the folder.  The video will appear there immediately.

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["upload.approach"] = "pull",
    ["upload.link"] = link,
    ["privacy.embed"] = "private",
    ["privacy.download"] = "false",
    ["privacy.comments"] = "nobody",
    ["privacy.view"] = "unlisted",
    ["name"] = title,
    ["description"] = description
};
    
if (parentFolderId != null) {
    parameters.Add("folder_uri", parentFolderId);
}
```