# How do I upload to a specific folder using the VIMEO API?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am using a PULL request with the VIMEO PHP Library but I can not find in the docs anywhere how to set the destination folder.

It just sends it to the "Videos" folder by default.

```
$response = $lib->request('/me/videos', ['upload'=>["approach"=>"pull",'link'=>$url], "name"=>$video['video_title']], 'POST');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vimeo API: how to save a vimeo into a subfolder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58238819/vimeo-api-how-to-save-a-vimeo-into-a-subfolder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to upload the video to your account first, then make an additional request that adds the video to the folder:

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/folders#add_video_to_project

Comment: yep, I guess that is the way :-). Thanks